# How to build regex capturing indices

Tags: python, regex

I have written regexes in uni for relatively simple expressions but now I'm struggling to get this one right. A sentence might look like this:

```
"Sentences can have no index in the end."
"Or one index.[10]"
"Or there even. Can be. Multiple sentences. And indices.[9][10][11]"
```

I want to cut off the indices in the end and just return the sentence. This is my first (to be fair here quite naive) approach: `.*(\[\d+\])+`. But it doesn't quite do what I need. I think my group on the right is correct. But `.*` doesn't do the right thing, because then it will just match anything and take the last `[0]` to match the `+`after the group.

Comment: Try  `re.sub(r'(?:\[\d+])+$', '', text)`

Comment: Does the indexes can be nested?

Comment: Yup it works.. need to wrap my head around that, I don't understand the `?:$` yet.. And yes that was really damn quick :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(?:\[\d+])+$', '', text)
```

The regex matches

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (used to group a sequence of smaller patterns that will be matched when they appear in immediate succession)

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `]` - a `]` char
- `)+` - one or more repetitions
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UoWC0g/1).

Comment: "Wiktor, I made a mistake.[1] Indices can be anywhere. Even after 'Hello'[2]. And strings are not limited to just one sentences. The index might be in the end,[3] but does not necessarily need to be.[4]"

Comment: To make it unambiguous, I want to filter wikipedia indices.

Comment: re.sub(r'\[\d+]', '', line)

Comment: @MarcelB You may remove `$` as it means the end of a string. `re.sub(r'(?:\[\d+])+', '', line)`. You may require a dot before: `re.sub(r'\.(?:\[\d+])+', '.', line)`. You may require any final punctuation: `re.sub(r'([!?.])(?:\[\d+])+', r'\1', line)`. Choose any that works best.